# beautifulsoup not returning span results

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm learning bs4 and trying to scrape the span tag data from this website put them in a list but no results are returned what am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
import bs4

root_url = 'http://www.timeanddate.com'
index_url = root_url + '/astronomy/tonga/nukualofa'

response = requests.get(index_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
spans = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'id':'qfacts'})
for span in spans:
    print span.string
```

All span data from the webpage is in between this tag

```
<div class="five columns" id="qfacts">
    <p><span class="four">Current Time:</span> <span id="smct">16 Mar 2015 at
12:53:50 p.m.</span></p><br>

    <p><span class="four">Sunrise Today:</span> <span class="three">6:43
a.m.</span> <span class="comp sa8" title="Map direction East">↑</span> 93°
East<br>
    <span class="four">Sunset Today:</span> <span class="three">6:56
p.m.</span> <span class="comp sa24" title="Map direction West">↑</span>
268° West</p><br>

    <p><span class="four">Moonrise Today:</span> <span class="three">1:55
a.m.</span> <span class="comp sa10" title="Map direction East">↑</span>
108° East<br>
<span class="four">Moonset Today:</span> <span class="three">3:17
p.m.</span> <span class="comp sa22" title="Map direction West">↑</span>
253° West</p><br>

    <p><span class="four">Daylight Hours:</span> <span title=
"The current day is 12 hours, 13 minutes long which is 1m 13s shorter than yesterday.">
12 hours, 13 minutes (-1m 13s)</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtle mistake is that you are searching for span tags that have an id of "facts" when what you really want is to search for span tags *within* the div having that id.

Replace,

```
spans = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'id':'qfacts'})
```

with,

```
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'qfacts'})  # <-- div not span
spans = div.find_all('span')  # <-- now find the spans inside
```

Were you looking for divs having some class you would want to iterate those divs and find all spans inside but this is an id so a single `find` call should suffice.